# Select con bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, jsp

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo una app web con jsp y bootsrap estoy realizando un formulario y le integre un select todo funciona pero se muestra mal, ya que los botones de enviar y cancelar se poner por encima de las opciones del select y no permite visualizar de forma correcta alguna idea de ¿por que ? gracias

estas son las librerías que ocupo

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

y este es mi formulario

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" action="../InsertarSub" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <%
            int idSub=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));               
            Querys DB=new Querys();
            SubCategoria subCat=DB.BuscarSubCategoria(idSub);
            out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idCat' value='"+idSub+"'>");
        %>

        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name:</label>
             <div class="col-xs-10">
                <%
                    out.println("<input type='text' name='nombreSubCat' class='form-control' value='"+subCat.getName()+"'>");
                %>
                 <span class="help-block">Name of Sub-categorie.</span>                        
              </div>
         </div><!-- form-group -->


         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Image: </label>
              <div class="col-xs-10">
                   <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" id="archivos" name="archivos">
                   <span class="help-block">Image of new Sub-categorie.</span>
                         <div id="vista_previa" style="margin-top:15px">
                              <%
                                  String foto="../img/SubAreas/"+subCat.getIdSubcategory()+"."+subCat.getFoto();
                                  out.println("<img src='"+foto+"' alt='' width='250' />");
                              %>
                         </div>
              </div>
         </div><!-- form-group -->                                

         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="area" class="control-label col-xs-2">Category: </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">                                                
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="area">                                                                                                                                                                                
                             <option data-tokens="x" value="x">x</option>                                                                                                
                        </select>              
                     </div>
         </div><!-- form-group -->

         <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">                                                
                   <table>
                      <tr>
                        <%
                            out.println("<td><input href='categorie.jsp?id="+subCat.getIdSubcategory()+"&name="+subCat.getName()+"' type='button' class='btn btn-default'  value='Cancel'  id='resetear'/></td>");
                         %>
                            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button></td>                 
                       </tr>                                
                     </table>             
              </div>
          </div><!-- form-group -->
</form><!-- form-horizontal -->
```

Comment: Recomendación: no utilices scriptlets. Esto dificulta la lectura del HTML generado/por generar, lo cual dificulta la labor de diseñadores de páginas web que conocen HTML pero no están familiarizados con código Java. Es mejor utilizar librerías adicionales que te permitan encapsular el código como JSTL en lugar de scriptlets, lo que facilita la lectura, promueve el reuso de fragmentos JSP a lo largo de tu proyecto y otros beneficios que no se consiguen con scriptlets.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo